# Changing from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I want to use mysqli instead of mysql but have no idea where to start, I searched but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Can this be done easily? If PDO is easier to add then that's okay too.

Thanks!

My php page:

```
    <?php

    require_once('connection.php'); // connectie


        if($_POST['action'] == 'button'){ // als de knop is ingedrukt insert dan
        if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('#\.[a-z]{2,6}$#i',  $_POST['email'])){

            $voornaam  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['voornaam']);
            $achternaam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['achternaam']);
            $email  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $telefoonnummer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefoonnummer']);

            $sql = "insert into 
               `form` (`id`,`voornaam`, `achternaam`, `email`, `telefoonnummer`) 
                values ('','".$voornaam."', '".$achternaam."', '".$email."', '".$telefoonnummer."')";     // insert query
            $query = mysql_query($sql);

            $subject = 'Een email van '.$voornaam.'';
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";   
            // opmaak mail
            $content = '<html><header><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF

-8" /> </header><body>';
        $content .= '<p>Je hebt een mail van:</p>';
        $content .= $voornaam;
        $content .= ' ';
        $content .= $achternaam;
        $content .= '<p>'.$telefoonnummer.'</p>';
        $content .= '</body></html>';

        mail($email, $subject, $content, $headers); // Verstuurd de mail
        error_log(E_ALL);
 }
    }
?>
```

And my connection page:

```
    <?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $gebruiker_mysql = "root";
    $wachtwoord2 = "";
    $DBNaam = "opdracht";

    $Verbinding = mysql_connect("$host", "$gebruiker_mysql", "$wachtwoord2") or die("<p>De verbinding met de database kan niet worden gemaakt</p>" . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($DBNaam) or die("<p>De database kan niet geselecteerd worden</p>");
    ?>
```

Comment: What does _I searched but couldn't find what I was looking for_ mean?

Comment: I searched on the internet on how to change from mysql to mysqli, but I could not fine a good explanation.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: there are lot of resources available. http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

Comment: @Twan search here in SO, there are a LOT of resources about that

Comment: no idea where to start ? php.net ! you are using `mysql_` functions, just use mysqli functions instead http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php
btw, there are frameworks to abstract SQL from the database used, like doctrine, using mysql/mysqli specific functions/methods is outdated

Comment: did you write this code yourself? I cannot imagine this to be so difficult if you already wrote this.

Comment: Yeah I did, but I always used mysql. And only changing the mysql parts to mysqli (as said in the answer under me) doesn't help because it can't connect to the database.

Comment: So do I need to add something to mysqli_query()? I read somewhere that there is a propertie that you need to include in the mysqli_query but I don't know what.

Comment: Got it to work. I forgot to add $msqli before the _POST's.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have major changes to work your script. Use this scrips
PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php'); // connectie
if($_POST['action'] == 'button'){ // als de knop is ingedrukt insert dan
    if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('#\.[a-z]{2,6}$#i',  $_POST['email'])){
        $voornaam  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['voornaam']);
        $achternaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['achternaam']);
        $email  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $telefoonnummer = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['telefoonnummer']);

        $sql = "insert into `form` (`id`,`voornaam`, `achternaam`, `email`, `telefoonnummer`) 
            values ('','".$voornaam."', '".$achternaam."', '".$email."', '".$telefoonnummer."')";     // insert query
        $query = mysqli_query($sql);
        $subject = 'Een email van '.$voornaam.'';
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";   
        // opmaak mail
        $content = '<html><header><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> </header><body>';
        $content .= '<p>Je hebt een mail van:</p>';
        $content .= $voornaam;
        $content .= ' ';
        $content .= $achternaam;
        $content .= '<p>'.$telefoonnummer.'</p>';
        $content .= '</body></html>';

        mail($email, $subject, $content, $headers); // Verstuurd de mail
        error_log(E_ALL);
    }
}
?>
```

and connection script:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$gebruiker_mysql = "root";
$wachtwoord2 = "";
$DBNaam = "opdracht";

$Verbinding = mysqli_connect("$host", "$gebruiker_mysql", "$wachtwoord2") or die("<p>Deverbinding met de database kan niet worden gemaakt</p>" . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($DBNaam) or die("<p>De database kan niet geselecteerd worden</p>");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use PDO with a chain class like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743773/153723

with PDO you don't need to `mysqli_real_escape_string` just bind and done