# using a pdo class wont return anything

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a pdo class from the net. Now when I want to use it in the auth class I received any result. Below I put some functions of my pdo.

```
public function query($query){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

//binds the inputs with the placeholders we put in place
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
        //$this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
        $this->stmt->bindParam($param, $value, $type);
}

//executes the prepared statement
public function execute(){
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}

// returns an array of the result set rows
public function resultset(){
    $this->stmt->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

// returns a single record from the database
public function resultRow(){
    $this->stmt->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Then here is how I use it in login function of my auth class.

```
public function login($user, $password){
//$pdo is a new of database class!
$pdo->query("SELECT user,pass FROM users WHERE user = ':user' , pass = ':pass'");     
$pdo->bind(':user', $user);
$pdo->bind(':pass', $password);
$result = $pdo->resultRow();
if($result == true) { //do sth
   return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

And it returns false! Since it's the first time that I use pdo in a php project, I'm a bit confused about using it.

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the PHP error logs? if on linux/apache server type: sudo tail -f /path/to/logs, which are set in your php.ini file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you really need an abstraction layer _on top of_ PDO?

Comment: I think I've seen the [original post you're referencing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6743773/2812842) here, and one of the great things about his example is that you can chain methods together - you need to `return $this;` at the end of your bind statement to allow this to happen (although I notice you aren't doing it in your implementation anyway)

Comment: @PatrickQ the idea of an abstraction layer is just that - abstraction. Using one means you can swap your datasource much more easily when an entire application uses your abstraction layer instead of specific PDO queries. Say you had to change to a remote API datasource or to SQLite or whatever, easier to write a new abstraction -> database class than it is to rewrite an entire project.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `''` around placeholders. That's the whole point of the placeholder. Remove `''` around `:user` and `:pass`.  The SQL you provide is invalid (in addition to this, you're using `,` instead of `AND` to join two parts of your `WHERE` statement).

You can also put PDO in a more suitable debug mode by setting `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. This makes debugging any SQL issues easier.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

In addition I'd like to comment that having "current" statements inside your PDO class is not a very flexible solution, and will cause leakage of open database handles. This is also true for leaking cursors in the case of the implementation of `resultRow`. It might not be an issue for a small web request, but if you try to reuse this code in a more persistent application, you'll run into issues.

It might be better to stick to the standard PDO for now.

Comment: I did the corrections. Now I get "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]". guess the problem is with this line "$result = $pdo->resultRow();" because the echo right after that doesn't work. But I don't know what the problem is! ofcourse it's the problem for now!!

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by issues coming from `resultRow`. The php itself do have any class that i can use it? @MatsLindh

Comment: @CodeLiker Directly using PDO, at least until you understand the basics, would probably be better. SQLSTATE[42000] is a general `syntax error` issue. If you print the message of the exception or dump the exception itself, you should see the actual error (try/catch/var_dump).

Comment: I was busy a week to make the db and auth classes (:shame) and now should let it go :) I'm just afraid that my professor doesn't accept it as a OO thing. Give another try and then may take your advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's all right with your PDO syntax, so check your $user and $password and connection to DB.

Also, using AND instead coma will be better.