# Benefiting from PDO Prepared statement when used in a function or method

Tags: php, pdo

Per http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

> The query only needs to be parsed (or prepared) once, but can be
>   executed multiple times with the same or different parameters. When
>   the query is prepared, the database will analyze, compile and optimize
>   its plan for executing the query. For complex queries this process can
>   take up enough time that it will noticeably slow down an application
>   if there is a need to repeat the same query many times with different
>   parameters. By using a prepared statement the application avoids
>   repeating the analyze/compile/optimize cycle. This means that prepared
>   statements use fewer resources and thus run faster.

As such, the following will benefit with improved performance when using a prepared statements:

```
<?php
...
$stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT a FROM mytable WHERE x=?');  //I often use globals or similar for $conn
foreach($array as $id){
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    $data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    ...
}
...
?>
```

To eliminate duplicated code, I wish to execute the query in a function.

How could I benefit from the improved performance of a prepared statement under this scenario?

Note the the following code provides no efficiency benefits, and is actually slower than not using prepared statements in the first place.

```
<?php
function getStuff($x)
{
    ...
    $stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT a FROM mytable WHERE x=?');
    $stmt->execute(array($x));
    $data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    ...
    return $data;    
};

...
foreach($array as $x){
    $data=getStuff($x);
    ...
}
...
?>
```

Comment: Make two functions, one for preparing, one for executing. In your situation, you're preparing the same query every time, which will not improve performance.

Comment: you don't benefit at all in your scenario. You prepare/execute your query, then THROW AWAY the statement handle that'd let you re-use the query.

Comment: Bv202 and Marc.  Agree my second scenario offers no benefit, only my first.  How can I benefit under the second scenario?

Comment: @Bv202  You said `Make two functions, one for preparing, one for executing.`.  Meaning I should call the function to prepare in the main script, then pass the prepared statement object to the second function to execute?  Or could a static variable or something be used?

Comment: Have a look at my question I've asked 4 years ago, it might help you :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740153/simple-pdo-wrapper

Comment: With the way you've got it organised you probably can't; `$stmt` will be discarded when the function exits. You *could* create an object which stores the prepared statement internally and has a method that allows you to throw an array of `ids` at it to retrieve *all the stuff* - but it's beginning to look a bit overkill unless you've got a **lot** of duplicate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this in the past:

```
function getStuff($x)
{
    global $conn;
    static $stmt;

    if (null === $stmt) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT a FROM mytable WHERE x=?');
    }
```

This works if the function is stateless.
For instance, it would not make sense to make the `$conn` variable an argument:

```
function getStuff($conn, $x)
{
    static $stmt;

    if (null === $stmt) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT a FROM mytable WHERE x=?');
    }
```

Because, the static statement won't necessarily belong to the supplied connection.

However you do it, you need to make the statement persist either within the function, or otherwise use the function as a factory and cache the statement elsewhere.

EDIT, testing non-oop scenario:

```
echo '<pre>';

function do_something()
{
    static $i = 0;

    echo $i . PHP_EOL;

    $i++;
}

do_something();
do_something();
do_something();
do_something();
do_something();
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: You can declare static variables inside functions (rather than as class members)? I'd never actually even thought of trying that :)

Comment: Thanks Flosculus.  Why won't your second version work provided it is always passed the same $conn?  I no I said I typically use a global for $conn, but in reality I use a static singleton class (probably the same effect).

Comment: @CD001 Apparently you can :P

Comment: Yeah - I've just re-read the docs : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php ... makes sense I guess but I'm so used to just creating objects ... `*Insert "the more you know" meme here*`

Comment: @user1032531 Because having a connection argument implies alternative connection instances can be supplied.  However, the statement (in this case) is directly linked to the "first" connection that created it.  Its just wrong, and it wouldn't work the second time if you supply a different connection.

Comment: If you are using a singleton class (although it also works for non-singletons), you don't need to use static.  You can store your prepared statements in a class property and use `isset` to reselect it.  It all depends on your favourite paradigm.  Also im pretty sure static variables are shared across class instances, something you never really want to do.